# How to solve "LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types." error?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

Code:

```
public MVCCreationOptions GetMVCOptions()
    {
        IQueryable<AType> aTypes = _mVDataReadService.GetRecords().AreActive<AType>();

        var creationOptions = new MVCCreationOptions
        {
            ATypes = aTypes.ToList()
        };

        return creationOptions;
    }
```

I am getting the error message as "Unable to cast the type '`XX.YY.ZZ.Models.IAbc`' to type '`XX.YY.ZZ.Models.Lookups.Complex.AType`'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types." in the following line

```
    var creationOptions = new MVCCreationOptions
    {
        ATypes = aTypes.ToList()
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the query first by calling a `.ToList()`:

```
IQueryable<AType> aTypes = _mVDataReadService.GetRecords()
    .ToList()
    .AreActive<AType>();
```

Comment: `.AreActive` is not populated as intellisense after `.ToList()`

Comment: What's `.AreActive<AType>`. Is it some custom extension method you have written? If it is an extension method on `IQueryable<T>` you could try adding an `.AsQueryable()` after the `.ToList()` method: `_mVDataReadService.GetRecords().ToList().AsQueryable().AreActive<AType>()`.

Comment: This won't include any "active" related selection criteria in the generated SQL's where clause and will result in sub-optimal performance as it will fetch unneeded records from the DB and create unneeded objects in the memory just to cull them later in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework does not support interfaces (not *yet*, I hope). Simple as that. So you can't include an expression targeting an interface in a linq query, even though the queried entities implement it.

You'll just have to add the expression to the query

```
_mVDataReadService.GetRecords().Where(r => r.IsActive)
```

You could also create methods like `GetActiveRecords()` for each entity that implements the interface.